# Using NSManagedObject from its MOC's `performBlock` call

Tags: objective-c, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I know I'm not supposed to pass managed objects between threads, but I was wondering if accessing a managed object directly from the MOC it's been registered to is fine.

For example:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = aManagedObject.managedObjectContext;

[managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
    aManagedObject.someProperty = "SomeValue";
    [aManagedObject.managedObjectContext save:nil];
}];
```

Or should I be using the `objectID` even in this example?

Answer (score 0):

Since the block is run on the context's queue, and since you are getting the context from the object. The code you have is modifying the object in the correct context, so I don't see a problem with it.